# "when" and "before" in past perfect tense

Tags: grammar

In these two sentences, do "when" and "before" mean the same? Can they be used interchangeably?

> I had worked for that company when I left.
>
> I had worked for that company before I left.

Comment: When you left what? The company? The country? What is the context? When did you work for the company, and when did you leave whatever it was?

Comment: Yes, the sentence lacks the context.

Comment: Sorry for the vague meaning. I left the company.

Comment: It's not logically possible to have **had** worked for the company either **when** you left or **before** you left. If you'd worked there **in the past**, then it's not possible for you to leave it when you're no longer there—or to have left it before you left it. In short, neither of the sentences make sense if you're talking about leaving a company that you've already left.

Comment: Also, nobody would ever say *I **was working** for the company **[when / before]** I left it* either. While that's at least understandable, it's redundant to the point of absurdity. People would simply say *I left the company.*

Comment: On the other hand, this would make sense: *I had **put in a lot of work** for the company **[when / before]** I left it.*

Comment: Upon careful consideration, I think the first sentence does not sound logical, but the second sentence is fine. For instance, I left the company in 2018. Before I left it, I had worked for it. Before 2018, I had worked for the company. What do you think?

Comment: Actually, if I add "for three years" to the sentence, for example, I think both are correct. "I had worked for that company for three years when /before I left it.

Comment: It's fine. I had worked for that company before or when I left [the country, the city etc. ad nauseum]

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence lacks the context. "I left ..." what? It may be the town, the country, and the like.

> I had worked for that company when I left (the town).

Here, the time conjunction 'when' means that the first action ("to work for that company") was quite separate from the second action ("to leave").

> I had worked for that company before I left (the town).

Here, the time conjunction 'before' implies the completion of the first action before the second started.

But if the first action is not separate from the second, i.e., one action caused the other, then the simple past tense is used, instead of the past perfect, in the when-clause :
*"When I opened the window, the cat jumped out."* (More natural than *"When I had opened . . ."*).

Comment: Sorry for the vague meaning. I left the company.

Comment: Ok, I've assumed it : 'I left the town'. However, 'when' is used with the past perfect to mean the first action is separate from the second.

Comment: This is fine. One can say: when I left or before I left is the interlocutor knows from where.